# Cannot redeclare exported variable ''

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a npm module in another directory that I'm using in another project using `npm link`, however when I import the module and try to use the function I get the following error a bunch of errors even though the typescript compiled successfully. Here is my tsconfig for the npm module:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "declaration": true,
      "outDir": "./lib",
      "strict": true,
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Here is the index.ts of the module:

```
import * as APIServices from "./API/API"
import APIPage from "./API/APIPage"

export { APIServices, APIPage }
```

And here is how I'm trying to use the package:

```
import APIServices from 'common-backend'

console.log(APIServices)
```

But when I run the file I get the following errors:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
../../common-backend/lib/index.js:3:1 - error TS2323: Cannot redeclare exported variable 'APIPage'.

3 exports.APIPage = exports.APIServices = void 0;
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../common-backend/lib/index.js:3:19 - error TS2323: Cannot redeclare exported variable 'APIServices'.

3 exports.APIPage = exports.APIServices = void 0;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../common-backend/lib/index.js:5:1 - error TS2323: Cannot redeclare exported variable 'APIServices'.

5 exports.APIServices = APIServices;
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../common-backend/lib/index.js:7:1 - error TS2323: Cannot redeclare exported variable 'APIPage'.

7 exports.APIPage = APIPage_1.default;
```

Finally this is the index.js that the errors are being thrown on:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.APIPage = exports.APIServices = void 0;
var APIServices = require("./API/API");
exports.APIServices = APIServices;
var APIPage_1 = require("./API/APIPage");
exports.APIPage = APIPage_1.default;
```

Is there something that I forgot to add in the tsconfig? Is this the fault of the compiler transpiling the typescript incorrectly? Or does it have to do something with the way I'm import and exporting the files? I've been scratching my head for a while on this one and nobody else seems to have had the same issue.

Edit:
Forgot to include the API class I'm trying to import:

```
import { Validators } from "./Validators"
import { APIRoute, Config } from "./helpers/Interface"
import { Router } from "express"
const router = Router()

class API {
    private config: Config
    private _routes: APIRoute[]

    constructor(config: Config) {
        this.config = config
        this._routes = []
    }

    get routes() : APIRoute[] {
        return this._routes
    }
    
    set routes(routes: APIRoute[]) {
        this._routes = [...routes]
    }
    
    /**
     * Add route to routes array
     * @param route 
     */
    addRoute(route: APIRoute) : void {
        this.routes.push(route)
    }

    /**
     * Instatiates existing routes in the routes array
     */
    loadRoutes() : void {
        for(const route of this._routes) {
            try {
                new route.module(router, route, this.config.authFunction)
            }
            catch(error) {
                console.error(route)
                console.error(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

export { API, Validators, router }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think will solve all your problems but your imports seem off. There are two ways of handling imports.

```
export default APIServices
```

And then you can import like you have

```
import APIServices from 'common-backend'
```

Whereas if you want to export multiple named things like you have

```
export { APIServices, APIPage }
```

You need to import them one of two ways

```
import { APIServices } from 'common-backend'
```

Or I think you can do something like this but I am less familiar with it because I personally don't like how it looks (I much rather just import what I need)

```
import * as CommonBackend from 'common-backend'
// then use CommonBackend.APIServices
```

Comment: Sorry I guess I should've given more context, I tried all those ways you mentioned and it still gives me the same errors. I've tried default exporting, importing single modules, importing all modules, but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the issue was that I was using ts-node to compile and run the code in the project using the package. I changed `node --inspect -r ts-node/register src/app.ts"` to simply `node ./dist/src/app.js` and that solved everything. Although not sure what underlying elements were causing the javascript not to be run properly.